# Perfect powers in fraction fields

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $k$ its fraction field, and let $n\geq 2$ be an integer.

If $x\in k$ and $x^n\in R$, must $x$ also be in $R$? Or if $x^n=r\in R$, must there at least exist an $s\in R$ such that $s^n=r$?

Obviously the answer is yes in a UFD, or more generally, a ring that's integrally closed in its field of fractions. I can't seem to prove this in general, though, or think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt 8]=\{a+b\sqrt8:a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$?
Then $\sqrt2=\sqrt8/2\in k$, $\sqrt2\notin R$, and $(\sqrt2)^3=\sqrt8\in R$.

Comment: So it's not true in general. Thanks!